# Python logging setLevel not logging

Tags: python, logging

Is there anything in this code that would explain why my info messages aren't going into the log. Properly formatted warnings and above are going into both log files.

Initializing logger:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
f = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s\n%(levelname)s: %(funcName)s %(message)s')
out = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename=self.f_stdout, maxBytes=1048576, backupCount=99)
err = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename=self.f_stderr, maxBytes=1048576, backupCount=99)
out.setLevel(logging.INFO)
err.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
err.setFormatter(f)
logger.addHandler(out)
logger.addHandler(err)
```

Usage:

```
logging.info('this doesnt get logged')
logging.warning('this gets logged to stdout and stderr with respective formatting')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never actually set the log level of the *root* logger object itself (the `logger` variable in your code). Both handlers and loggers have log levels; lines only reach the output if they're above both thresholds.

Since you don't set the root log level, it uses its default (warning). Try adding a call to `logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` to change that.

Comment: This has been bugging me since 1995 - THANK YOU!!